# Hive Streaming exception : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy

Tags: hive

I am trying to do hive steaming using scala, from a standalone scala jar.
with the code snippet below

```
val hiveConfig = new HiveConf
hiveConfig.addResource(new Path("file://<path to core site>"))
val hiveEP = new HiveEndPoint(hiveConfig.getVar(ConfVars.METASTOREURIS), 
<database_name>, <table_name>, new java.util.ArrayList[String])
val hConnection = hiveEP.newConnection(true,hiveConf,"")
```

but the exception below is encountered at :

```
val hConnection = hiveEP.newConnection(true,hiveConf,"agent_name")
```

**NEED TO KNOW WHY THIS EXCEPTION IS COMING AND TO SOLVE THIS.**

I am using the sinature of newConnection as

*`public StreamingConnection newConnection(final boolean createPartIfNotExists, HiveConf conf, String agentInfo)`*

### Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/IMetaStoreClient;
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:227)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:202)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveMetastoreClient(HCatUtil.java:558)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.getMetaStoreClient(HiveEndPoint.java:544)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:312)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:278)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint.newConnectionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:215)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint.newConnection(HiveEndPoint.java:192)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint.newConnection(HiveEndPoint.java:162)
        at com.example.HiveStreaming$.main(HiveStreaming.scala:33)
        at com.example.HiveStreaming.main(HiveStreaming.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/IMetaStoreClient;
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$5.call(HiveClientCache.java:230)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$5.call(HiveClientCache.java:227)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4792)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late but might help someone.
This happens because if not all packages in the dependency chain are available in the spark cluster. Make sure all the packages as maven jars or referenced correctly as part of the spark submit configuration.